# http to a Node server over https nginx website

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ssl, https

Is it possible to have a http connection to a node.js server over a website which is generally secured by https ?

how do you suggest to combine a node connection with a website that is operating on https .

Comment: Are you saying you would like https ://yoursite.com to be handled by nginx and http ://yoursite.com to be handled by Node?

Comment: No , I have my site in https://example.com  but inside this website there is a chat feature , that is on node.js http on port 3000 , but I realized the website being on https breaks the connection to node.js ...

Comment: What kind of "break" is this? Is this a CORS one? Because normally CORS would forbid to call another port (443 to 3000).

Comment: no, the browser should block all non-secure requests without a config change

Comment: I have no Idea what CORS is , what do you guys suggest ?

Comment: @CapCa what do you mean by "break" ? I have a chat feature that uses node.js and over http , It needs to connect to node sever . does this http work on a website mainly in https ?

Comment: Depends on the browser. In some browsers it is still allowed but in most of them it is denied. You can simply make a small workaround by creating a reverse proxy to your node.js. In other words, make a route /chat (on the https domain) which redirects to the port 3000 route. There are a lot of tutorials which shows this

Comment: @CapCa thanks , this stupid website just blocked my questioning ability because my previous questions wasn't upvoted enough .

Comment: @CapCa Do you have links to any good article on how to have a proxy on Nginx for a Node.js chat server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it is useful to create a proxy to your node.js applications. 
A good tutorial is, for instance, from DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

In this tutorial, it shows that the host configuration can look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

In this case, a reverse proxy to the port 8080 was created. Generally, this method can be used for every node.js application.

In your case: add the location block in your https server block and modify the route.

Answer (score 0):

Support for https was just added to [node-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-http-server) it can spin up both http and https servers at the same time. It also has some test certs you can use and a cert generation guide for self signing.

***note if you want to spin up on port 80 and 443 you'll need to run with sudo***

An example for spinning up the same code on both http and https :

```
var server=require('node-http-server');

server.deploy(
    {
        port:8000,
        root:'~/myApp/',
        https:{
            privateKey:`/path/to/your/certs/private/server.key`,
            certificate:`/path/to/your/certs/server.pub`,
            port:4433
        }
    }
);
```

Its super simple and has pretty good [documentation](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-http-server) and several examples in the examples folder.

Comment: Thanks for your attention .